# ReferenceError: path is not defined at Object.handle

Tags: node.js, express

js file,

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(_dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

node.js can start ,but I got this error,

> ReferenceError: path is not defined at Object.handle
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\app.js:12:15)
>   at next_layer
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:103:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:107:5)
>   at
>   E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:195:24
>   at Function.proto.process_params
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)
>   at next
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19)
>   at Layer.expressInit [as handle]
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:23:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:226:17)
>   at
>   E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9
>   at Function.proto.process_params
>   (E:\javaEEstudy\node.js\node.js入门经典\socket\socket.io_express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)

the index.html and app.js is on the same file ,express version is 4.x

Comment: replace "_dirname" with "__dirname"

Comment: thank you.I solve the problem.

Answer (score 19):

First you should use

```
res.sendFile()
```

instead of

```
res.sendfile()
```

Second, the parameter of the above-mentioned method should be

```
__dirname+'index.html'
```

instead of

```
_dirname+'index.html'
```

In other words

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); 
});
```

Also you have to declare `path` in your Node.js app:

```
var path = require("path");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Node server is running..');
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to add an explanation to your answer to point out what is the problem.